# How to create Android Activity Navigation?

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to create button click to navigate one activity to another activity screen looks like iPhone navigation. Here below I have added another activity call code but if I use this code I can call another activity with popup option. I need navigation Right to Left with second activity page back button...

```
Intent intent = new Intent(AppMainActivity.this, ForgotPasswordActivity.class);
                AppMainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you can use animation and maybe this tutorial is your friend

http://www.christianpeeters.com/android-tutorials/tutorial-activity-slide-animation/

Sorry I'm not familiar with formatting links correctly in stack overflow. Hop it is allowed to post link directly like this..

In the activity which slides from left to right I would place a back button with a ''reverse animation'' which just slides back from right to left the activity you started from. Hope it helps..

**Update**

Regarding to your second question in the coments below:

Simply create two more XML-files in the anim ordner and call them animation3.xml animation4.xml:
animation3 include:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromXDelta="-100%p"
android:toXDelta=" 0%p"
android:duration="500">
</translate>
```

animation4:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromXDelta=" 0%p"
android:toXDelta=" 50%p"
android:duration="500">
</translate>
```

and call These XML-files in your onCLick-Method of the Back-button the same way you did before for slide to the nex activity ! ;-)

**It's important for you to know that:**

**fromXDelta** means the Offset on the X-Axis in centum. Example: 100%p means view is on the right sight completely out of view(for your eye, because in reality, the Animation is just an Illusion, it's not really sliding out). Example 2: 50%p means it half slided to the right, so 50% of the view is visible on the right side of your Screen.

**toXDelta** means where you want to slide(direction) and how far you want to slide

**Duration** gives you the power to decide how much time the Animation should take until it's finished. The duration is setted in milliseconds.

So now you are more flexibly of using transitions.

English is not my native language, but i give my best to make it clear to you. I hope it helps you.

Comment: Strange, it works for me.. Then just type in Google tutorial-activitiy-slide-Animation :-) @Ajay

Comment: If it fits your Need, please mark as accepted answere :-). But i think it's exactly what you looking for - You Welcome @Ajay

Comment: Hi @mike...Abive links shown error at line       ActivityOptions.makeCustomAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.animation,R.anim.animation2).toBundle(); "anime" cannot reolved or its not a field error...

Comment: @Ajay did you create a Folder in your res Folder called anim? And did you put in there 2 XML files with the Name Animation.xml and animation2.xml? And does These two XML-files include exactly the code from the tutorial please check this... Check if you typed every Name correctly

Comment: hi @Mike I need another one help…I want to create “Back button click to revert First view from second view”….Could you Please post some code related my question….?

Comment: @Ajay you mean you want to slide back to your activity where you started from? Notice, a view is not an activity..

Comment: Yes...Second Activity back button click to revert first screen.(Like iPhone app)...

Comment: I've updated my question above to fit your new Needs. Just try :) @Ajay

Comment: wow...Your Rocking @Mike...Sorry for the long disturbance...Actually I am a new person for Android...Anyway nice stack post about Android navigation process made by Mike and all...

Comment: @Ajay i've updated my question again to make it more clear to you how the Transition works. Just read it carefully and expand your know-how ! ;-) you'are welcome

Answer (score 0):

This code should work for you:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(AppMainActivity.this, ForgotPasswordActivity.class);
startActivity(intent); 
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.enterAnimation, R.anim.exitAnimation);
```

You need overridePendingTransition() method as this will handle transition animation between activities.  Just create an animation xml and save it in your resources. Here are some examples of animations.

enter_from_left.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:shareInterpolator="false">
 <translate 
  android:fromXDelta="-100%" android:toXDelta="0%"
  android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
  android:duration="700"/>
</set>
```

enter_from_right.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:shareInterpolator="false">
 <translate
 android:fromXDelta="100%" android:toXDelta="0%"
 android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
 android:duration="700" />
</set>
```

exit_to_left.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:shareInterpolator="false">
 <translate 
  android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="-100%"
  android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
  android:duration="700"/>
</set>
```

exit_to_right.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:shareInterpolator="false">
<translate
 android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="100%"
 android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
 android:duration="700" />
</set>
```

Answer (score 0):

My example here. The activity will slide in when added and slide out when click back:

1. slide_in_left.xml

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <translate
         android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
         android:fromXDelta="-100%p"
         android:toXDelta="0%p" />

    <alpha
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
        android:fromAlpha="0"
         android:toAlpha="1" />

    </set>
   ```
2. slide_out_right.xml

   ```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

     <translate
   android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
   android:fromXDelta="0%p"
   android:toXDelta="100%p" />

    <alpha
   android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
   android:fromAlpha="1"
   android:toAlpha="0" />
   ```

3. slide_in_right.xml

   ```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <translate android:fromXDelta="100%p" android:toXDelta="0%p"
       android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"/>
      <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1" 
       android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"/>

    </set>
   ```
4. slide_out_left.xml

   ```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <set  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <translate android:fromXDelta="0%p" android:toXDelta="-100%p"
       android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"/>
      <alpha android:fromAlpha="1" android:toAlpha="0.0" 
       android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"/>

   </set>
   ```

And in the activity :

```
public class ThirdActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    static int count = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.sample_activity);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
        button.setText("" + count++);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        if(arg0.getId() == R.id.button){
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, ThirdActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    };

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);
    }
}
```

You can copy the layout also :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/flContainer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Click me" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your valuable replay...@gZerone... But I solved the problem by using above @Mike post...any way Thank you so much@gZerone...